# How to perform mysql command using python subprocess inside docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, subprocess

I have a python script that performs operations on a mysql db using the python module subprocess. I am new to docker and trying to run this code using docker.
I have created a docker compose file to run a container for my python script and a container for my mysql db. The MySQLConnection object from the mysql-connector module works fine, but I would like to use the subprocess module to perform a mysql operation on the mysql container. How would I go about This?

This works:

```
db = MySQLConnection(host="mysql-container", user="root", password="secret")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW SCHEMAS")
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

This gives error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mysql': 'mysql'".

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["mysql", "-h", "mysql-container", "-P", "3306", "-u", "root", "-psecret"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("source sql_file.sql")
```

Comment: do you have mysql client installed on the host machine?

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the insight! I wrongly installed the mysql client on the host container. It is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, as it turns out, host machine was missing mysql client.

However, in general unnecessary exposure of container ports is not a good practice. Instead, I would consider running commands within the container, something like:

```
docker exec -t container_name bash -c "echo mysql_command | mysql [params]"
```